# How to make a AsyncRunner request in Android to get data from Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a user's likes and here is what I did:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
mAsyncRunner.request("https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes", new RequestListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
       try {
           JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
           final String name = json.getString("data");
       } 
       catch (FacebookError e) {
           Log.w("fb", e.toString());
       } 
       catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.w("fb", e.toString());
       }
    }

    public void on<XXX>Exception( ...)
        ...
}
```

The reponse I was expecting is something similar to graph explorer where you have "data" and "paging". But instead, without getting any errors or exceptions, I get something like {"id":"https://graph.facebook/100000234..../likes"} for response and a JSONException for not finding JSONObject["data"]. What could be the cause of this.